# vector does not get appended and is NULL. Why?

Tags: r, if-statement, null

I don't know why, but the vector is NULL after running the function. I have checked manually that the if-condition is true for at least some rows of my data frame. If I rund the if statement for i=84, for example, it gives me back TRUE. How can it be possible then, that the vector does not get appended, i.e., is NULL after running the function? I tried and checked at least three times....

```
my_vector <- c()
my_function <- function() {
  for (i in 1:20640) {
    if (cal_housing$Median_Age[i] >= 10 & cal_housing$Median_Age[i] <= 20) {
      my_vector <- append(my_vector, cal_housing$Median_House_Value[i])
    }
  }
  #print(mean(my_list))
}
my_function()
my_vector
```

Comment: Functions return the value of the last statement run and here that is the `for` statement which returns NULL. Try this:  `x <- for(i in 1:3) i; x`   To fix this explicitly return the output.  In the future please make your questions reproducible so that others can run it as requested at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: You made the assignment within a function, so you modified a new variable in that function, you didn't modify the global variable.  The normal way to do this is for your function to return the modified copy, and use `my_vector <- my_function()` to save the result.

Answer (score 0):

Running it within a function is probably a problem. Do you need it in a function? If no then just run the for loop on its own.

If you want to be efficient you can get a boolean vector and then just subset from there.

```
lower = cal_housing$Median_Age >= 10
upper = cal_housing$Median_Age <= 20
nums_to_include = lower & upper

my_vector = cal_housing$Median_Age[nums_to_include]
my_vector
```